# Google Cloud ML Engine: Apply Custom Function Before Training / Predicting

Tags: machine-learning, google-cloud-ml

I currently pre-process some data on my laptop before passing it to ML Engine for training. Is it possible to apply a custom pre-processing function to my data and then train, all within ML Engine?

So instead of these steps:

1. Pre-process data on laptop.
2. Send pre-processed data to ML engine for training.

I would do:

1. Define pre-processing function for ML Engine
2. Send raw data to ML Engine, where it will:

   a) pre-process my data by applying the function I've specified and

   b) train on that data

Is this possible and, if so, how would I do it?  I don't see anything in the docs.

Thanks!

Comment: @rhaertel80 I'm using TensorFlow

Comment: What type of data are you using?

Comment: @spicyramen Mostly text data

Answer (score 1):

You can use some of the samples code [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/blob/master/flowers/sample.sh):

Pre-processing is done using [DataFlow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/) and then training in ML Engine using the output generated during the pre-process phase.

Comment: This is super helpful.  Can it be used at prediction time as well, though?

Comment: That is correct, you can use Batch predictions and use as argument/input the Google Bucket path which was generated by Dataflow for predictions. This link contains more information: https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/deploying-models

Answer (score 1):

For preprocessing TensorFlow models, consider TensorFlow Transform ([Getting Started Guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/transform/get_started)).

You may be interested in the [chicago_taxi](https://github.com/tensorflow/model-analysis/tree/master/examples/chicago_taxi) example, which includes a script for integrating the preprocessing with classification on Cloud ML Engine.

Comment: Been looking at it for a bit now and playing with the Chicago taxi example.  One question though: is there a better / easier approach for text-based preprocessing?  E.g. tokenizing, stemming, etc.  Looks like TF Transform is a bit limited in that regard.  Thanks again!

Comment: If it doesn't have what you want, maybe sklearn will be a better fit for preprocessing. If you contact us at cloudml-feedback@, we can give you access to an Alpha feature that should allow you to do sklearn preprocessing with a TensorFlow model.